# 1&1 server, htaccess deny from all except localhost

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, localhost

I'm triying to allow a directory access only by my server.

Basically I have this:

```
-- Datas
    -- .htaccess
    -- Script
    -- file.json
-- AngularJS app
    -- ...
    -- myService
```

I want to access file.json or script in myService in the angularJS app
This is my actual .htaccess

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

That's not working, I have a 403 error, forbidden access.

When I put my personal computer IP adress instead of 127.0.0.1 it's ok.

Do you have any answer?

Actually, it seems to be because the request is done by my browser(my ip) and not by the script on the server.
How can I execute this request on the server so?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't `allow from 127.0.0.7` be `allow from 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: you'd need to figure out what IP is used for the outgoing connection you're doing to your own server. it won't necessarily be 127.0.0.7. take off the block, run whatever code it is you have to, then look at the access log to see what IP did get used. That's the IP you need to allow.

Comment: And where can I see in my logs the requests for this file?
I have access.log.XX but I see only my personal IP with my browser requests and nothing on my server.